# Wordpress 404 page nightmare

Tags: wordpress, error-handling, wordpress-theming

I've created my first custom theme and I wanted to style my 404.php page so that consist theme remains site wide. I have permalinks that all work fine using the /%postname%/ option but cannot for the life of me get my 404 page, or any other to load.

If I type in mysite.com/i-dont-exist or mysite.com/i-dont-exist.php it seems that I am redirected somewhere else, but I don't know where, I can not find the associated file. On top of that the page doesn't load correctly.

At the very top of the page I have the following random left over code

```
nt_entries">
```

Then the page has the main headings 'Recent Posts', 'Most Used Categories', 'Archives', 'Tags'. Then seems to load in my themes footer file, but without any of its css styles.

To aid with debugging of my theme in each file I chucked in a h1 tag with the filename inside of it so I could see when each theme file was used and how they interacted with each other. Theoretically the page that I'm seeing should display the headings 'header.php', '404.php' and 'footer.php' but all I'm seeing is the 'footer.php' heading, there isn't even a page heading from any of the other files I've created and I have test in the same manor to see if it was the generic root based index.php file and it isn't.

It seems to me that whatever page is being called, its not calling in my themes header file with the link to the style sheet, and nor is it finding my custom 404 file.

My htaccess file is as follows, but even without the errordocument line it still gives the same results

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Does anyone know what might be going on? I'm at a complete loss, swiching themes made no real difference.

Comment: Try switching themes, does that work?

Comment: I just tried that, it seems to part load some of the footer content but none the the other stuff I had previously and that was using the 2012 theme.

I did however still have redundent code at the top of the page, this time saying 'ze.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Faprilkelley.org.uk%2Fi-do-not-exist">Customize'

Comment: Can you post an URL to the misbehaving site?

Comment: its http://aprilkelley.org.uk/

Comment: does anyone have any ideas?